# decorators to class methods called without class instantiation?

Tags: python, decorator

In the code below I created a decorator to my class `Class` methods. I noticed that this decorator is called even without creating a class instance!
And without calling these methods in the class!

Is there any explanation for that?

### decorator :

```
def deco(class_name):
    def inner_function(method):
        print("method is = {} and class is: {}".format(method.__name__,class_name.__name__))
        return method
    return inner_function
```

### class_deco

```
class class_deco :
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

### Class:

```
class Class :
    def __init__(self):
       pass

    @deco(class_deco)
    def f1(self):
        pass

    @deco(class_deco)
    def f2(self):
        pass
```

When I run the script :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

I get this result:

```
method is = f1 and class is: class_deco
method is = f2 and class is: class_deco
```

Comment: The decorators are executed when the decorated definition is executed. In this case, when the class is defined. Whether or not it is instantiated is irrelevant. Perhaps it would help you to explain why you expected something different.

Comment: @SaifFaidi Why would you want the decorator not to be executed when the function is defined? What would be your use case for that? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Please don't make such substantive changes to your question. If you do, then comments and answers will no longer make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators are just syntatic sugar for the following

```
@deco(class_deco)
def f1(self):
    pass
```

is same as -

```
f1 = deco(class_deco)(f1)
```

So this code runs as soon as the module is imported just like any other name declaration would and `f1` name is replaced with decorated f1 as above.

Comment: thank you!  can you suggest a solution to avoid this calling ! and just call decorator when the method is explicitly called :  i mean `Class().f1()` ?

Comment: So, did you mean `@deco def f1(self):` ? What was the point of `class class_deco:`?

Comment: @Saif you can write a decorator that returns actual decorator.

Comment: @quamrana , i edited my question you are alright ,i  want to know if there is an other way to avoid this calling ! so i want it to be called only  when it's explicitly implemented

Comment: The reason is that you are using the wrong syntax for decorators. Most often it is `@deco`. Occasionally the decorator itself has a parameter: `@deco(param)`.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained, the `@decorator` syntax is only syntactic sugar, so this:

```
@somedecorator
def foo():
    pass
```

is stryctly equivalent to

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = somedecorator(foo)
```

In you case, you ARE explicitely calling the decorator function:

```
@deco(class_deco)
def f1(self):
    pass
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def f1(self):
    pass

 _effective_decorator = deco(class_deco)

 f1 = _effective_decorator(f1)
```

which is why your `inner_function` is indeed executed at import time.

Decorators that take additional params needs one more level of nesting, so technically your decorator should look like:

```
def deco(cls):
    def real_deco(func):
        def inner_function(*args, **kw):
            print("method is = {} and class is: {}".format(func.__name__,cls.__name__))
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return inner_function
    return real_deco
return inner_function
```

BUT if the point is to get the name of the class the method **really** belongs to, this is still broken - you should get the class from the instance on which the method is called, not try to hard-code it in the decorator call (which will never work as intended since the real class doesn't exist when you're applying the decorator to the function). So the proper implementation would look something like:

```
def deco(func):
    # we're only supposed to use this on methods...
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        print("class {} - method {}".format(type(self).__name__, func.__name__))

    return wrapper


class Class:
    @deco
    def f1(self):
        pass
```

NB: this won't handle classmethods nor staticmethods, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo showing just two possible ways a decorator could be constructed:

```
def Deco(*deco_params):
    print('In Deco', deco_params)
    def deco(func):
        print('In deco(func)')
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print('In inner(*args, **kwargs)')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return deco

def deco(method):
    print('In deco(method)')
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print("method is = {} called".format(method.__name__))
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_function


class Class :
    def __init__(self):
       pass

    @deco
    def f1(self):
        pass

    @Deco(42)
    def f2(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Now in Main')
    c = Class()
    c.f1()
    c.f2()
```

Output:

```
In deco(method)
In Deco (42,)
In deco(func)
Now in Main
method is = f1 called
In inner(*args, **kwargs)
```